# SQL Server: date incompatible with int when migrating from mysql. How to solve?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, date, int, migration

I have similar databases, they come from the same CMS but they use different databases: some are originally SQL Server, and another one is MySQL.

I had to migrate the MySQL database to SQL server since I have some scripts ready for SQL Server which a. a don't want to convert, b. are more complicated to convert since some functions I use are not implemented in MySQL.

This query on the database which were originally SQL Server runs without problems:

```
SELECT Birth_Date+1 FROM TABLENAME
```

while, when I run it on the same table in the database I migrated from SQL, I get this error:

> Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int

Any idea why I get this error and how I can solve it?

I migrated my database with SSMA, SQL Server Migration Assistent, if this can help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error seems pretty clear.  You can't add an integer to a `date`, although you can add an integer to a `datetime`.  Presumably, the data type of  `Birth_Date` is `date` in one database and `datetime` (or something similar) in the other.

Here are two solutions:

```
SELECT cast(Birth_Date as datetime)+1 FROM TABLENAME;

SELECT dateadd(day, 1, Birth_Date) FROM TABLENAME;
```

Comment: Hello Gordon, effectively it's a type problem. Either I have date as type, instead of datetime, or datetime2(0), type which I don't know. I'll try to remigrate or solve with the cast. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The message is rather clear, you can't use the `+` operator with a date and an int.

You should use the `DATEADD` function (in Sql Server)

And `DATE_ADD` in mysql.

`DATE_ADD(Birth_Date, interval 1 DAY)` for example.

which is

`DATEADD(day, 1, Birth_Date)` in Sql Server